# paginate text and adjust its size

Tags: android, text, pagination

what I want is exactly what ThinkFree Office pdf viewer **Reading View** does.

I have a bunch of text and I want to be able to adjust it's size (users can choose from different zooms) and the text should paginate accordingly, I want it to wrap the screen, so that the user doesn't have to 'move' the screen, the rest of the text will show on the next page.

I know how pagination works, but how can I determine how much text has fitted the screen, so I know what to show on the next page?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look here this might help you with a solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: good, but I'm looking for pagination, not auto-fit. Because the zoom should depend on user. Goal of the app. is to offer comfortable reading, not to fit the text into the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I mean't that you could adapt the codebase there by turning off the resizing part and just using it to paginate. It definitely would need work to make it fit this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: yeah maybe that would work, but I haven't had time to play around with it, so I just put it in a scrollview